# Django Rest Framework, default serializer for foreign key field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose a user has an address as a foreign key

A typical PrimaryKeyRelatedField would represent foreign key by id:

```
{

   id: 3,
   first_name: eugene,
   last_name: kim,
   address: 9  # here 9 is address's id
}
```

I'd like to change the default representation of foreign key field changed as in the following example. (Hopefully without me defining serializer for every foreign key field)

```
{
   id: 3,
   first_name: eugene,
   last_name: kim,
   address: {
     id: 9     # difference here,
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField(PrimaryKeyRelatedField)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if self.pk_field is not None:
            return self.pk_field.to_representation(value.pk)
        return {"id": value.pk}
```

**Update**

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    serializer_related_field = MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField
```

Then replace `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` to `MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField` and
`serializers.ModelSerializer` to `MyModelSerializer`

Comment: Thank you. PrimaryKeyRelatedField is automatically used for foreign key field. Would it be possible to set MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField as the default serializer field for foreign keys though?